# i want to build search bar to fetch user posts by their title

Tags: flutter, search

I have already built a search bar for all the users

As I am passing userList to the search page, but I don't know how to do the same with documentSnapshot like user posts etc.

```
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final suggestionsList = query.isEmpty
        ? userList
        : userList.where((p) => p.displayName.startsWith(query)).toList();
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: suggestionsList.length,
      itemBuilder: ((context, index) => ListTile(
            onTap: () {},
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(suggestionsList[index].photoUrl),
            ),
            title: Text(suggestionsList[index].displayName),
          )),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'or' like this way

```
Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final suggestionsList = query.isEmpty
        ? userList
        : userList.where((p) => p.displayName.startsWith(query)).toList() || p.displayPost.startsWith(query)).toList();
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: suggestionsList.length,
      itemBuilder: ((context, index) => ListTile(
            onTap: () {},
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(suggestionsList[index].photoUrl),
            ),
            title: Text(suggestionsList[index].displayName),
          )),
    );
  }
```

Comment: posts are different collection inside users collection not a field, but your answer is interesting thanks

Comment: @Kuldeeprawat, it is depends on your model stricture, but work like this way